# Is there a code on java that allows for two if statements with one independent statement for Shipping Charges?

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I am very new to java and have been stuck on a program that I've been trying to create. For background knowledge purposes, the program is for a company called "Ship It" which is a package shipping company. The user enters the weight of the package, and the distance it will travel. Depending on the weight, the company charges a fee **per 200 miles.**

0 < weight <= 3 pounds  $1.00 charge

3 < weight <= 6 pounds  $2.00 charge

6 < weight <= 10 pounds $3.00 charge

10 < weight <= 20 pounds  $4.00 charge

20 < weight <= 30 pounds  $5.00 charge

So far, this is the code I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    //Variables
    double costWithoutCharge = 0, weight, distance = 0;
    
    //Introduction to ShipIt
    System.out.print("\t\t******Welcome to ShipIt******\n");
    System.out.print("***We are a low-charge, secure shipping company for packages" +
                        "up to 30 pounds***");

    //User Enters Weight of Package
    System.out.print("\n\nEnter the weight of the package (1.0 - 30.0 pounds): ");
    weight = kb.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("");
    

    // User Enters distance the package will travel
    System.out.print("Enter the miles to the destination (1 - 2000 miles): ");
    distance = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.print("");
    
    //Weight If-else Statement
    if (weight >30.0)
        System.out.println ("\nSorry, you have entered invalid data - program terminated");
    if (weight >30.0)
        System.exit((int) weight);
    
    //Distance Restriction if-else
    if (distance >2000)
        System.out.println ("\nSorry, you have entered invalid data - program terminated");
    if (distance >2000)
        System.exit((int) distance);    
    
    costWithoutCharge = distance / 200;
    
    //If else 
    if (weight <0 || weight <=3)
    {
        System.out.println ("The cost to ship the package is: "+ "$" + (costWithoutCharge)*1.00);
    }

    else if (weight <3 || weight <= 6)
    {
        System.out.println ("The cost to ship the package is: "+ "$" + (costWithoutCharge)*2.00);
    }

    else if (weight <6 || weight <= 10)
    {
        System.out.println ("The cost to ship the package is: "+ "$" + (costWithoutCharge)*3.00);
    }

    else if (weight <10 || weight <= 20)
    {
        System.out.println ("The cost to ship the package is: "+ "$" + (costWithoutCharge)*4.00);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println ("The cost to ship the package is: "+ "$" + (costWithoutCharge)*5.00);
    }

    kb.close();

}
```

}

As of now, if I put a value like 1001, the cost to ship is $15.015, but it should be $18 since the charge is multiplied per 200 miles. I am on the fence if I need to do a new equation for the charge per 200 miles dilemma or if it can be supported with another if-statement?

I feel as though I have tried everything but I can't seem to solve this ): I am in dire need of help! Please!

Comment: Please note: in programming, every character you put in your code, you have to understand what they mean. You have plenty of strange (copy / paste?) errors like doing the same `if (distance > 2000)` twice in a row. Thing is: dont do that. Understand every line in your code, and dont just copying/modifying code on the fly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weight is missing from your example.
it sounds like in your example you have:

- distance 1001
- weight between 6 and 10, resulting in a $3 charge per "beginning 200 miles"

From your code, 15.015 gets returned.

It appears you want to calculate the "beginning 200 miles", so you could achieve that by rounding up:

```
costWithoutCharge = Math.ceil( distance / 200 );
```

On another note, you may want to remove the common parts from your if/then/else block. That is, only perform the calculation but not the System.out.println inside each clause.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem. I haven't learned about Math.ceil yet but am now knowledgeable of it. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First

```
if (weight <0 || weight <=3)
```

should be

```
if (0 < weight && weight <=3)
```

However the code should be easier to maintain, use a table of limits:

```
double[][] weightsAndCharges = {
    {3, 1.00},
    {6, 2.00},
    {10, 3.00},
    {20, 4.00},
    {30, 5.00}
};

double charge = 10.00;
for (double[] weightAndCharge : weightAndCharges) {
    if (weight <= weightAndCharge[0]) {
        charge = weightAndCharge[1];
        break;
    }
}
System.out.printf("The cost to ship the package is: $%0.2f%n", charge*distanceRatio);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is some basic math.

What you are thinking of is a combinatorial explosion: If you layer a whole batch of `if`/`elseif` statements inside each of your weight `if` statements for e.g. `if (miles < 200) ... else if (miles >= 200 && miles < 400)` - then think of it in dimensions: You have the 'miles' dimension which currently is adding 10 options (1-200, 200-399, 400-599, etc), the weight dimension which adds 5.

The amount of ifs you'd need here is then A*B: 50 ifs.

That's a ton, and clearly not what you want.

Math to the rescue!

You really just want to calculate `costPerSegment * segments`.

Calculate those 2 values individually, and now it's just A + B: 15 ifs. Given that you can actually use math itself to turn the miles number into the # of segments you need to charge (it's just division by 200 for the miles part, no lookup table involved), we're down to 5 ifs.

Note also your code is buggy. Your weight `if` statement have their `>` and `<` reversed. But the `else if` hides the problem. I fixed that problem in the snippet below.

```
double costPerSegment;

if (weight <=3) {
  costPerSegment = 1.0;
} else if (weight <= 6) {
  costPerSegment = 2.0;
} else if (weight <= 10) {
  costPerSegment = 3.0;
} else if (weight <= 20) {
  costPerSegment = 4.0;
} else {
  costPerSegment = 5.0;
}

// Casting a positive double to an int automatically rounds down.
int segments = (int) miles / 200;

double cost = costPerSegment * segments;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing the problem for input distance 1001

`costWithoutCharge = distance / 200; // result = 5,005`

As far as I understood you want to have here just 5

So the simpliest solution would be to declare costWithoutCharge as int
and than

`costWithoutCharge = (int) distance / 200; // result = 5`

Or if you want to keep costWithoutCharge as double you can use Math lib to round it

`costWithoutCharge = Math.round(distance / 200); // result = 5`